# Query a xml file from a url

Tags: ios, xml, xcode

In my iOS application project I have a string which holds an address and I was given a url of a xml file that holds a list of addresses and precinct locations like so:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
<root>
    <row>
        <res_street_address>448 IVY YOKELEY RD</res_street_address>
        <res_city_desc>WINSTON-SALEM</res_city_desc>
        <state_cd>NC</state_cd>
        <zip_code>27101</zip_code>
        <precinct_desc>GUMTREE # 16</precinct_desc>
    </row>
```

This file is very large and takes a long time to load in my browser.  My job is to find the precinct location for a given address in this app.  I have been at this for days and I’m about at my wits end.  Everything I’ve found so far leads me to believe that I will have to download the file first and then parse it.  This file is VERY large and this will slow the app down.  Is there a way that I can do a query on the records in the xml file and then download those results?  I’ve tried

```
https://thewebaddress/voter.xml/?res_street_address=”448 IVY YOKELY RD”&res_city_desc=”WINSTON-SALEM”…
```

but  I’ve found this isn’t the way to do this.  I have very little experience with web technologies, so a lot of what I find online is over my head.  What is the best way to go about something like this?

Comment: Use NSURLSession, as the data arrives parse it using a SAX style XML parser. Google around - you will find out more on how to do this.

Comment: You are right the is no way to do a query on it. you have to download it. a proper solution would be to download the file once when the app starts. but the more logical one and easiest is to ask the person responsible of the server is to create a web page/service that takes res_street_address and res_city_desc as params and retrieves only the the exact address

Comment: this way you can hit the http request with the parameters in the query string as the link example you provided

Answer (score 0):

## you can't natively do that with a xml file.

**a xml file is purely data and contains no 'programming' that could fulfil your search request**. to WORK with an XML you have to download it. (you CAN work with a byte stream and a SAX based XML Parser and only download as much as it needs to find your result... but thats a small optimisation and not worth the trouble IMO)

#### point is: the DATA you want to work with HAS to be loaded

(a way would BE to install a script (php/asp/whatever) to have this scan the xml on the server side and that would then only serve you the relevant xml parts)
[I would recommend this if you can. It saves CPU & bandwidth -> time & battery

Comment: Thanks to all for the advice.  At least I have a direction to work towards now.